# How to draw a centered line with a rectangle to one side in CSS

Tags: html, css, gwt

I'm pretty novice when it comes to styling.

I have a web app (built with GWT) where I'm presenting a grid of results, and in one column, I want to display a visualization of a score, where there's a center black line, and either a green rectangle to the right for a positive score, or a red rectangle to the left for a negative score.  The size of the rectangle indicates the value of the score.  Something like this:
[image]

I have a div for the entire cell; I think what I need to do is add two sub-divs, somehow draw the center line, and then add the rectangle to the appropriate div.  I"m just a little confused about how to do all that.

I have this:

```
 @Override
        public SafeHtml getValue(SearchResult value) {
            SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();

            float ratio = value.getRatio();

            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;'>");

            if (ratio > 0) { 
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style='position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 1'><div style='display: inline; float: left; width: "
                        + ratio
                    + "%; height: 20px; background-color: #82cd80;'></div>");
            }
            else {
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style='display: inline; float: right; width: "
                    + ratio
                    + "%; height: 20px; background-color: #c54c4d;'></div>");
            }
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
```

But it doesn't draw anything.  I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have two divs per graph. One goes around the whole graph (like a cover) while the other just goes around the bar itself for the graph. The cover is how you'll get your line. Set a border right on it so it should look like this:

```
border-right: 2px solid color;
```

(For the other graph just do border left)
Now I'm not sure on what you're using as I've never used "SafeHtml" but it looks like it's using the basic HTML features throughout so as long as you know where to place it this should be fine.